# If somebody just says "暇か", what does that mean exactly?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence

The setting is 4 kids in a park in Japan. The kid sitting on the bench is Ageru-kun, who is uploading a video to the internet, which is illegal in Japan. His 3 friends go up to him and have the following conversation.

> あげるくん遊ばないの？
>   Aren't you going to play, Ageru-kun?
>
> 昨日の番組をネットに上げてから
>   Ageru: I'm uploading yesterday's program to the internet
>
> またかー
>   Friend A: This again?/ Not this again!/ Oh, not again! (Not sure which one exactly)
>
> 暇か
>   Friend B: spare time; free time; leisure (Not sure which one exactly)
>
> 見られなかった人のために上げているんだよ
>   Ageru: I'm uploading it for those who couldn't see it

Comment: Thanks all of you! I was stumped by what this could mean. It's funny how I can read whole manuals and understand lengthy videos, but 2 words had me pulling my hair in confusion.

Answer (score 6):

This could be pretty loosely translated something like "You got nothin' to do?" or "*Somebody's* got a lot of free time," said in a sarcastic manner. Thus, I'd say it would fall under the "spare/free time" category.

Comment: Also translating it as "Get a life!" may not be too far from the intention of friend B

Comment: @Tuomo You're a lifesaver! I would've never guessed anything even close to that. I can't say thanks enough.

Comment: Thank @J28 instead. He/she already told you in the 1st example "You got nothin' to do?"

Answer (score 1):

「[insert a single noun/na-adj.]か！」 (*exclusively with a falling intonation*) is a quite viral slang/meme template for a while, where they find useful to tell roughly the following emotions with as terse as one extra syllable overhead:

- "Come on! Why are you so —?"
- "What a (f–ing) — are you?"
- "Like it's such a —, huh?"

I believe this construction originated from the comedian group タカアンドトシ's signature joke, most well-known in a fixed phrase 欧米か！ "As if (you're in) the West!" (which is said by トシ (straight guy) after タカ (funny guy) plays something stereotypically Western drama). Due to its versatile simplicity, it quickly gained popularity that now I almost hear it once a day on Twitter or reality. The choice of word before か is crucial in this pattern.

Though it's partially true that this usage can be explained as an original sense of particle か, I remember we usually needed to phrase ～かってんだ, ～じゃん（かよ）, or ～なのかよ for similar connotation before the meme. Also, this type of か is only grammatical after a noun or na-adjective in theory, but recently I start to see something like [かわいいかよ](https://note.mu/marketing/n/nee1a23dc44e7) which is an obvious anacoluthon but IMO very effective.

Comment: TIL the word “anacoluthon”...